# Promise not resolving even with status of fulfilled and target data on PromiseResult

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I need help on this issue I'm experiencing (I have already searched Stack overflow extensively but could not solve it on my own).

I have the following "dummy" logic to test async/await behaviour:

```
const data = [1, 2, 3]

async function newData() {
  return data
}

async function getData() {
  const fetchedData = await newData();
  return fetchedData
}

console.log(
  (async () => await getData())()
)
```

Even though I have awaited for all Promise fulfillings, the following data is returned from the console log:

[Console.log return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w04nc.png)

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't the Promise return the value but remains pending even though it is 'fulfilled'?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `async` functions return a promise.  That's why `newData()`, `getData()` and your `async` IIFE you have buried in a `console.log()` ALL return a promise.  When you return a value from an `async` function, that returned value just becomes the resolved value of the promise that the `async` function returns.  An `async` function NEVER returns the value directly.

So, even this:

```
(async () => await getData())()
```

is an `async` function that returns a promise.

To get the resolved value from an `async` function, you MUST use `.then()` or `await`:

```
// this must be inside an async function or
// in an environment where top level await is allowed
console.log(await getData());
```

or:

```
getData().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
});
```